# Nick is invisible in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

While clearing a building of raiders, I turned to Nick, and he was invisible, like you'd be with the chameleon armor. I can see where he is, but I see through him. I don't think he equipped armor. How did he turn invisible?

UPDATE: He just became visible again. Still have no idea how he went invisible...

Comment: Check and see if he does have any armor on. If they have chameleon armor on and crouch, they will turn invisible when still just like you would.

Comment: @TimmyJim Nick can't wear armor.

Comment: Probably just a weird bug. Note if it ever happens again.